# RDLC Sub Report in ASP.NET MVC using Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, asp.net-mvc-5, rdlc, subreport

I'm facing problem in generating **RDLC Sub Report** using **ASP.NET MVC 5** Visual Studio 2019 using **LINQ query**.
I have two tables `PartyType` and `Customer` which is shown in Image given below. I want to show `PartTypeName` in Main Report and then according to that party Customer data will Show In SubReport RDLC. [image][image]

This Type of Output I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is creating a master/detail report. There are tons of articles and videos online. Just do an online search for `SSRS master detail example`.